# What’s the difference between a reflexive and intensive pronoun?

Tags: british-english, pronouns

There are a few types of pronouns, among other there are reflexive and intensive pronouns. Every website I visit, they give me the same examples.

E.g. 
Found on Grammar Monster:
• Reflexive pronouns (e.g., itself, himself)
• Intensive pronouns (e.g., itself, himself)

What is the difference?

Comment: Reflexive pronouns have two main uses: a **complement** use where they are obligatory, as in "Ed hurt himself", and an **emphatic** use where they are optional, as in "Ed designed the house himself". It's the latter use that is sometimes called 'intensifying'.

Comment: @BillJ that should be made an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1] *Ed hurt himself*.
>
> [2] *Ed himself designed the house*.

Reflexive pronouns have two main uses:

a **complement** use where they are obligatory, as in [1], and an **emphatic** use where they are optional, as in [2].

It's the latter use that is sometimes called 'intensifying'.